# Git repo must match directory structure on disk? What about project where code lives in diff directories?

Tags: git

Sorry I would assume this question has been asked a million times but I can't find an answer, so here goes...

I've got a lot of legacy code I'd like to check into git but my source code isn't stored in the same directory on disk. As an example I have a project where the there are email reports(cronjobs) that live in /usr/local/bin/. The project has backend php scripts that live in /var/www/html/project/. I'd love to be able to leave the code on disk where it currently resides and check these different directories into a new repo project_x that has directories reports/(that has the scripts in /usr/loca/bin) and a directory www/ (that has the scripts in /var/www/html/project/).

In searching around it sounds like git doesn't follow symbolic links, so have read standard advise to be - create hard links to put all the code into a common directory(or other games like bind mounting) that can be checked into git. I can do that, but hate adding unnecessary complexity to a project and that seems like what I'm doing with this approach. e.g. Hey team remember if you want to check-in changes for this project you can't do it where the code has always resided, you have to remember about this new magic directory with hard links so we can use git...

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Please note I've oversimplified the problem for communication...

Comment: I think you should consider having the files reside in the git working tree and then have symbolic links from the places where they were to the working tree.

Comment: A Git "project" will always consist of a "root folder" and "subfolders".  All of your artifacts under version control should reside under the root folder.  And no: you should *not* use symbolic links.  For many reasons.

Comment: It's generally wise to have "source" in location A, and "deployment" in location B, where A and B are entirely separate. In your case, B may be many separate sub-B's.

Comment: I've been doing this by having a git repository and generate a .rpm (or deb, or whatever) and install the config throug the package manager of the distro. This eases updates, and limits the need to put a .git in /

Comment: 1) The *artifacts* under Git should be stored under the project root, and should not use links (hard link, symbolic links or windows shortcuts).  2) The artifacts can (and should) include *deploy* scripts (Makefiles, Gradle builds, Powershell or Bash scripts - whatever).  3) The Git Workflow can (and should) involve"automation" (Jenkins, GitLab - whatever)  4) The automated workflow can deploy as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have two possible choices here.

One is that your code is all part of the same project.  In that case, it makes sense to check it in in one directory (that is, one Git repository) and deploy it to those locations on disk something like `make`, `capistrano`, or some sort of other deployment or packaging tool.  You'll edit it in that one project and it will live together, but you won't be able to edit it in its final destination on disk.

The other is that your code is in multiple independent projects, which is ideal if the code components are logically independent of each other.  In that case, you can have multiple different repositories stored in different locations on disk, and they can evolve independently of one another.  Note that this will be problematic if the code *isn't*, in fact, independent of each other and doesn't expose a fixed, versioned interface.